# How to make search engines not to read .php extension urls

Tags: php, .htaccess, clean-urls

How can I restrict the search engine not to read our .php url because we want our clean urls to appear in search engines.

I am using htaccess file for removing .php from all the urls but the search engine is taking both the urls i.e. with .php and without .php.

I want to make the search engines read only the urls having NO .php extension.

Comment: Just ask them nicely not to crawl your Web page!

Comment: That is not possible unless you change the html of the said page to add a no-index whenever php is present in the URL

Comment: Premanent redirect file.html => file,

Comment: Hi Starkeen, you can explain it more because I have spent more than enough time on this. Please

Comment: You can use a permanent redirect in your htaccess that will redirect files with extension to files without extension. permanent redirect tells search engines to update their dbs with the new url.

Comment: I am trying to do so but codes not working, if you can give me codes.

Comment: Post your code in question.. so that i can help u.

Comment: RewriteRule ^index\.(php|html?)$ https://www.example.com/ [L,R=301] this is the rule i am writing for index page redirection but i want the same for all my pages like if someone tries to use https://www.example.com/about-up.php it will redirect to root,while the page https://www.example.com/about-up work properly

Comment: Hi @Starkeen please let me know whether you can help.  Thanks again.

Comment: @AnirudhPoddar You can't redirect your orignal files to root, if you do so, your rewritten urls will also point to root. You need a rewrite rule that **rewrites** both urls with extension and without extension to its destination path. I can post an answer if you edit your question with your currunt htaccess rules.

Answer (score 0):

Create a robots.txt file in your website root and include the following to avoid crawling .php extensions.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /*.php$
```

Ref: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt?hl=en